# Rake rollback migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

While migration i migrated the files with a wrong name, and now i rolled these files back and need to make another migration, but i cant, following message appear:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "name" character varying(255), "email" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
```

How could i rollback the whole migration process, or clean my DB tables?
Im using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE users;
```

or

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm :) Im so newb shame on me :)